# Software engineering best practice with database population

Tags: database, reflection, polymorphism

Sorry for the non-descriptive title but I really couldn't think of what to put.

I was thinking of the best way to link together an item in the database with functionality in the code.

Say for instance that I have game types Tennis, Football and Basketball. These will be held in the database within a GameType table.

Now the functionality to print out the score for a given game will be different for each game type. So what I have at the moment is a class structure like this:

```
public abstract class GameType {
    String name;
    public abstract String getScore(Score s);
}

public class Tennis extends GameType {
    String name = "Tennis";
    public String getScore(Score s){
        // Do something here specifically for tennis
    }
}

public class Football extends GameType {
    String name = "Football";
    public String getScore(Score s){
        // Do something here specifically for football
    }
}
```

So my question is:

What is the best practice or programming pattern for linking an entry in the database with the correct class? At the moment I am using reflection to grab the class that has the same name as the entry in the database but I am not convinced this is the best option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a small application you can study the [DAO pattern](http://java.sun.com/blueprints/corej2eepatterns/Patterns/DataAccessObject.html) which is a standard pattern for database interaction.
For larger application you should look into an ORM model e.g. [Hibernate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernate_%28Java%29)

Comment: Thanks, the DAO pattern helps. I think Hiberate is too heavy for what I am looking at.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an object relational mapper (ORM), such as [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/Default.aspx). This will map relational data to one of your classes so that you can easily populate objects with attributes from a database